# how do you get iron in Story of seasons?

Tags: story-of-seasons

i know stupid question but im trying to make a sewing studio and i need 5 iron. how do i get iron?

Comment: oh also its for a ring for klaus <3

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get Iron is to buy it.  The Silk Country sells a few every time they're in town, for 1000G each.

You can also get some from the mining spot in the Safari; what you get is random, though, so if you really, REALLY want some, you might have to save before mining, and reload if you don't get any.

You can also get some by diving in the river; I've had good luck in the zone with the grain and rice paddy fields.

And if worst comes to worst, you can also arrange to trade with a friend by visiting their farm and them having a gift of Iron for visitors.

By far, though, Iron is cheap.  Just clean out the Silk Country stall every chance you get.

Comment: thats very helpful. btw i tryed the mining and i got rare stuff...not iron. i have bad luck with iron..ing.